# Why Visual Studio 2012 generated web service proxy class starts with lowercase letter?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, visual-studio, soap

I am using [Add Web Reference] on Visual Studio 2012, the proxy classes generated, but the only problem is the class name start with lowercase letter. That really makes me crazy.

```
context xcontext = new context();
```

Help me please, how to correct it to uppercase.

Comment: Are you using WCF or legacy ASMX web services?  They are not the same thing (ASMX is no longer supported actively by MS); to add a WCF service you use "Add Service Reference".  You indicate you used "Add Web Reference", which is for the older ASMX.

Comment: yes, I found "Add Web Reference" in the Advance button on "Add Service Reference", so, I should use "Add Service Reference"?

Comment: It depends.  Are you connecting to a legacy ASMX service or a newer WCF service?

Comment: actually, the web service I connected is a java web service, I just fillin the WSDL url to use it.

Comment: What's the WSDL for the service that you are trying to use? It might be that WSDL specifies classes in lower case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the WebService is in java, decorating the java classes as follow let have Uppercased C# classes.

> Try this:
>
> ```
> @XmlType(name="ProtocolItem")
> public class ProtocolItem {
>    ...
> }
> ```
>
> from [Change WSDL xsd:complexType name with Apache CXF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556816/change-wsdl-xsdcomplextype-name-with-apache-cxf)

And if you also wants the method with the first letter uppercased, set "operationName":

```
@WebMethod(operationName="Ping", action="ping")
@WebResult(name="pingReturn")
public String ping() {
    return "Pong";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the question really old... I even lost my project environment...I will accept your answer because it looks good.