# Change WSDL xsd:complexType name with Apache CXF

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, cxf

I use Apache CXF to publish a webservice, generating the WSDL "on-the-fly". This works great, but I would like to change the naming convention of the generated types. As the service clients (C#) generate code based on the WSDL, the default xsd:complexType naming results in type names starting with lower-case letters.

Here is an excerpt from the generated WSDL:

```
<xs:complexType name="protocolItem">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="data" type="tns:protocolItemData"/>
  <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="elements" nillable="true" type="tns:protocolElement"/>
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="meta" type="tns:protocolItemMeta"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

This is the Java code that results in the above WSDL fragment:

```
@RooJavaBean
public class ProtocolItem {

    private ProtocolItemData data;
    private ProtocolItemMeta meta;
    private List<ProtocolElement> elements;

}
```

How can I change the generated WSDL to use something like `<xs:complexType name="ProtocolItem">`?

Hopefully I am not missing a obvious annotation... Thanks!

**EDIT**: thanks for the first answer! So there is a way to do this "per class" - can I configure the CXF naming conventions? Would be nice if I did not need to annotate all classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
@XmlType(name="ProtocolItem")
public class ProtocolItem {
   ...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work! Is there a way to change the default naming convention or do I have to annotate all my classes with @XmlType?

Comment: Yep! You should annotate classes with `@XmlTyp(name = "name")` and members with `@XmlElement(name = "name")`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am happy to award you the bounty as your solution worked well (though I like using Aegis more).

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Aegis](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/aegis-21.html) data binding instead of the JAXB data binding with Apache CXF helped: This changed the naming convention. Unfortunately, I realised this after having added all @XmlType annotations, so I removed them again...

I stumbled over Aegis when searching for a solution for collections/arrays - they are not wrapped with JAXB, but with Aegis, which is required for proper client code generation (typed collections instead of arrays).